# Python Basics: for i, element in enumerate(seq)..why/how does this work?

Tags: python

Hello I've found an intersting snippet:

```
seq = ["one", "two", "three"] #edited
for i, element in enumerate(seq):
    seq[i] = '%d: %s' % (i, seq[i])

>>> seq
['0: one', '1: two', '2: three']
```

I wonder how python is doing that.... for me element should be undefined...but obviously it isn't..what does python do here?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`enumerate` essentially turns each element of the input list into a list of tuples with the first element as the index and the element as the second. `enumerate(['one', 'two', 'three'])` therefore turns into `[(0, 'one'), (1, 'two'), (2, 'three')]`

The bit just after the `for` pretty much assigns `i` to the first element and `element` to the second for each tuple in the enumeration. So for example in the first iteration, `i == 0` and `element == 'one'`, and you just go through the other tuples to get the values for the other iterations.

Comment: thats for your explaination... to me this tupel thing was not clear

Answer (score 2):

The actual definition of enumerate function is like this

```
enumerate(iterable[, start]) -> iterator for index, value of iterable

Return an enumerate object.  iterable must be another object that supports
iteration.  The enumerate object yields pairs containing a count (from
start, which defaults to zero) and a value yielded by the iterable argument.
enumerate is useful for obtaining an indexed list:
    (0, seq[0]), (1, seq[1]), (2, seq[2]), ...
```

But the parameter seq if not defined will not return the desired output, rather it will throw an error like- NameError: name 'seq' is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure what you want, to know enumerate or what's happening here in this .
may this can help :

```
seq = ["one", "two", "three"]
for i range(3):
    seq[i] = '%d: %s' % (i, seq[i])

>>> seq
 ['0: one', '1: two', '2: three']
```

actually , here "seq" is object of list-class. Each element in list reference to independent object of different class . when in above function ;
first you get the reference of each list element's object by accessing "seq[i]", you create a new object using referenced object value (can belongs to other class),
now u again referencing the "seq[i]" to new created object for each element .

Answer (score 0):

You are right. seq is not defined. Your snippet will not work. It will only work if seq has ben set to seq = ['one', 'two', 'three'] before. Just try it!