# struggling to understand this 'advanced' for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I know how to do basic for loops but I'm struggling to understand the for loop in this code snippet. I am looking for a way to find a substring within a list and grab the index (so I can take that string and slice it - in this example, extract the value 25 given there is a list item X minute[s]).

This code works and returns 3, but I am struggling to understand i for i etc. - I've only ever worked on for loops that start with for. Note i haven't defined i or s. I do understand the enumeration.

Note theres probably other ways to do this but when I started down this road I realised I didn't understand the many examples I found which are similar to the for loop below, so I'm fixated now on understanding this method.

Much appreciate the explanation in advance

```
uptime list = ['routerX uptime is 2 weeks', '6 days', '4 hours', '25 minutes']

min_index = [i for i, s in enumerate(uptime_list) if 'minute' in s]
```

Comment: This is an example of a list comprehension. It basically has three parts to it: the first `i`, the `for i, s in enumerate(uptime_list)`, and the `if 'minute' in s`. The first part is a sort of mapping, the second defines the domain, and the third is the filter operation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Basics: for i, element in enumerate(seq)..why/how does this work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14499762/python-basics-for-i-element-in-enumerateseq-why-how-does-this-work)

Comment: Oh, it's just another way of writing `map(lambda l: l[0], filter(lambda l: 'minute' in l[1], zip(range(len(uptime_list)), uptime_list)))` *fun fun fun*, (I think this is why they put list comprehensions in Python and deprecated `map` and `filter`).

Comment: Incidentally, it doesn't return `3` - the number three, it returns `[3]` - a list containing the number three. This matters and maybe it helps show the similarity between the use of `[  ]` list building characters in both your lines of code.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler: `map` and `filter` aren't deprecated. Guido did briefly argue for that in 3.0, but everyone else convinced him otherwise, and instead he gave us _improved_ versions. If you have an expression to map, like `l[0]`, constructing a function with `lambda` just to call `map` is silly—but if you have a function already lying around like `spam`, writing a call expression (`spam(i) for i…` instead of `spam`) just to avoid `map` is just as silly. Also, the multi-argument form of `map` can be handy sometimes.

Comment: @abarnert I felt `l[0]` was silly; I tried tuple-unpacking in the lambda and failed. But I see it can work: `map(lambda (i, s): i, filter(lambda (i, s): 'minute' in s, zip(range(len(uptime_list)), uptime_list)))` - now it keeps the same `i, s` bits that the original post has. OK, not deprecated, but... "deprioritised"? Scorned? Shunned? Branded *unPythonic*? I didn't realise there was a multiple argument map - sort of mapzip? Neat. What sort of use does that have, does that pattern have a common name to Google?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler: Well, the expression `i` is obviously still less verbose than the function `lambda (i, s): i`. Personally, I never use `map` unless I've got a named function (or bound or unbound method, or a `partial` I've already created for some other reason, etc.) to pass, but I think to some extent it's just a matter of taste; some people who I think understand "Pythonic" better than me use it more often than I do.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler: As for the "mapzip", I don't really know of a name for it (that's why I used the clumsy term "multi-argument `map`). A few times I've written `map(f, zip(…))` and then realized I didn't need the `zip`. In 2.x (but not 3.x) you can use it as a non-lazy no-fillvalue `izip_longest`. But the most common use I've seen is actually not that compelling: as an alternative to using `partial` or `lambda` to bind in an argument, like the `map(pow, a, repeat(2))` example in the `itertools` docs, which would only be your first thought if you were translating from Haskell in your head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first term here, `i`, is what gets returned for each iteration of the loop (assuming the condition is true - more on that later).

In the second part, `for i, s in enumerate(uptime_list)` the `enumerate` function will make the list of strings into a list of tuples that can be iterated over like this:

```
>>> for x in enumerate(uptime_list): print(x)
(0, 'routerX uptime is 2 weeks')
(1, '6 days')
(2, '4 hours')
(3, '25 minutes')
```

Then, multiple assignment happens for each iteration in the loop. For example, if you do `x,y = 0,1` then `x` will be 0 and `y` will be 1. The only difference is that in this case, the tuples are coming from the `enumerate` function and are being assigned to `i` and `s`.

Finally, the last portion, `if 'minute' in s` will only cause the first `i` to be returned when the condition is true (i.e., when "minutes" is in the `s` variable that is currently being looked at). If you add a second term to `uptime_list` containing the string "minutes", `min_index` will then contain multiple numbers because the condition will be true for multiple elements in the list.

Answer (score 1):

The function `enumerate()` will return a list of tuples in the form `[(0, element1), (1, element2), ...]` and a conditional list comprehension is used to filter that list, finally only the indexes are chosen.

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions can be directly translated to explicit `for` statements.

You take everything from the first `for` clause and nest them as separate statements. In the innermost statement, you `append` the expression before the `for` clause to the list. That's the entire rule. So, this:

```
min_index = [i for i, s in enumerate(uptime_list) if 'minute' in s]
```

… means:

```
min_index = []
for i, s in enumerate(uptime_list):
    if 'minute' in s:
        min_index.append(i)
```

For a longer explanation, see [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in the official tutorial.  For the fully gritty details of the syntax and semantics, see [Displays for sets, lists, and dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries) in the language reference.*

---

If you don't understand [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), that's just a way of getting both the index and value of each element of a list (or other iterable). `For example, enumerate(['x', 'y', 'z'])` gives you `(0, 'x')`, then `(1, 'y')`, then `(2, 'z')`.

So, each time through the loop, `s` is one of the values from `uptime_list`, and `i` is the index of that value. So at the end, we have a list of all the indices from `uptime_list` whose corresponding values included the string `'minute'`. For example, given this:

```
uptime_list = ['20 seconds', '3 minutes 5 seconds', '17 seconds', '1 minute']
```

You'll get `[1, 3]`, because elements #1 and #3 contain `minute`.

---

<sub>* Note that some of the details have changed over time, so if you're using an older version, especially a 2.x version, switch to the right version in the docs.</sub>

Comment: cheers - where does the append come in? and when you break it down to multiple lines the enumeration is crystal clear - but where is the initial i? (as in 'i for i')EDIT just read http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python, makes sense, thanks

Comment: @wintermute000: To help improve the answer: I wrote "you append the expression before the `for` clause". In this case, that's the first `i`. How can I make that clearer?